# The Second Hearts Problem

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

According to the last part of these [lecture notes](http://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/martingales.pdf), if we have a standard deck of playing cards and turn cards until the first heart appears,
the probability that the next card is a heart is $\color{red}{1/4}$.

---

[image]
[image]

---

Without using probability theory, this looks to me like we are computing:

$$E[ \ \mathbb P(Y_{N+1} = 1 | Y_N = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < N\}}) \ ]$$

where:

1. $N$ is a discrete random variable whose range is $\{1,2,...,40\}$, indicating the first time a heart is turned over (I guess $N$ is a stopping time, but I don't believe I'm using probability theory)
2. $\{Y_i\}_{i \in \{1,2,...,52\}}$ are binary random variables indicating whether or not the $i$th card is a heart,

as follows:

$$E\left[ \ \mathbb P(Y_{N+1} = 1 | Y_N = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < N\}}) \ \right]$$

$$= E\left[ \ \sum_{n=1}^{40} \mathbb P(Y_{n+1} = 1 | Y_n = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < n\}} ) 1_{\{N=n\}} \ \right]$$

$$= E\left[ \ \sum_{n=1}^{40} \frac{12}{52-n} 1_{\{N=n\}} \ \right]$$

$$= \sum_{n=1}^{40} \frac{12}{52-n} E\left[ \ 1_{\{N=n\}} \ \right]$$

$$= \sum_{n=1}^{40} \frac{12}{52-n} \mathbb P(N=n)$$

$$= \sum_{n=1}^{40} \frac{12}{52-n} \frac{13 \cdot P(39,n-1)}{P(52,n)} = \color{red}{1/4}$$

---

**Questions:**

So what then is the following quantity (in plain English):

$$\mathbb P(Y_{N+1} = 1 | Y_N = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < N\}}) = \sum_{n=1}^{40} \frac{12}{52-n} 1_{\{N=n\}}$$

?

That to me looks like

$$P((n+1) \text{th card is hearts} \ | \ n\text{th card is first heart})$$

So how is that different from what we are computing which again is

$$E[ \ \mathbb P(Y_{N+1} = 1 | Y_N = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < N\}}) \ ]$$

?

The latter to me seems something like expected probability while the former is probability.

Comment: Using `\mid` instead of `|` leads to better spacing.

Comment: In the first equation with a sum, it should be $i\lt n$ instead of $i\lt N$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We should compute for

$$E[ \ \mathbb P(Y_{N+1} = 1 | Y_N = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < N\}}) \ ]$$

rather than

$$\mathbb P(Y_{N+1} = 1 | Y_N = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < N\}}) = \sum_{n=1}^{40} \frac{12}{52-n} 1_{\{N=n\}}$$

because the latter computes

$$P((n+1) \text{th card is hearts} \ | \ n\text{th card is first heart})$$

meaning a certain card is already given to be the first heart while the question does not assume a certain card is given to be the first heart.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb P(Y_{N+1} = 1 \mid Y_N = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < N\}})$ is a random variable (I hope that term exists in plain English?) that's a function of the random variable $N$.

You're comparing it to $P((n+1) \text{-th card is hearts} \mid n\text{th card is hearts})$, by which I suspect you mean more precisely $P((n+1) \text{th card is hearts} \mid n\text{-th card is the first hearts})$. This is similar, but with a small $n$: $\mathbb P(Y_{n+1} = 1 \mid Y_n = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < n\}})$. This is a (conditional) probability, not a random variable; it has a particular value for every particular value of $n$.

You ask how this differs from the quantity $E\left[\mathbb P(Y_{N+1} = 1 \mid Y_N = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < N\}})\right]$ being computed. This is the expected value of the random variable $\mathbb P(Y_{N+1} = 1 \mid Y_N = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < N\}})$, where $N$ takes all values of $n$, not a particular value.

In concrete terms, we have

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y_{n+1} = 1 \mid Y_n = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < n\}})&=\frac{12}{52-n}\;,\\
\mathbb P(Y_{N+1} = 1\mid Y_N = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < N\}}) &= \sum_{n=1}^{40} \frac{12}{52-n} 1_{\{N=n\}}\;,\\
E\left[\mathbb P(Y_{N+1} = 1 \mid Y_N = 1, \{Y_i= 0\}_{\{i < N\}})\right]&=\sum_{n=1}^{40} \frac{12}{52-n} E\left[1_{\{N=n\}}\right]
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{40} \frac{12}{52-n} \mathbb P(N=n)\;.
\end{align}

I don't feel sure that I've addressed your question, but if not, hopefully I've at least provided a basis on which we can address it further.

Comment: Not sure about your first sentence. Consider that $A=[Y_N=1,\forall1\leqslant i\leqslant N-1,Y_i=0]$ is an event hence $P(Y_{N+1}=1\mid A)$ is a conditional probability in the elementary sense, that is, a real number. Re the question itself, $A=\Omega$ hence $P(Y_{N+1}=1\mid Y_N=1,\forall1\leqslant i\leqslant N-1,Y_i=0)$ is simply $P(Y_{N+1}=1\mid A)=P(Y_{N+1}=1)$, which shows how useless this quantity is (not in the linked notes, of course).

Comment: joriki, it's like this: 1 my understanding is that the question asks for $\text{P((n+1)th card is hearts | nth card is first heart)}$. 2 My understanding is that that depends on $n$. 3 The book gives an answer that does not depend on n. So what's going on? where did i misunderstand?